# How do I use values in a list to dynamically create columns in a dataframe using each value in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe "pets" that looks like this:

```
PERSON  | WEEK       | CAT | DOG | BIRD
------------------------------------------------
000001  | 2016-08-29 | CAT | 0   | 0
000002  | 2016-07-25 | 0   | DOG | BIRD
```

And currently I have code that replaces any instances of "CAT", "DOG", and "BIRD" in the appropriate columns with a 1:

```
pets$cat <- ifelse(pets$cat== "cat", 1, 0)
pets$dog <- ifelse(pets$dog== "dog", 1, 0)
pets$bird <- ifelse(pets$bird== "bird", 1, 0)
```

What I'm looking to do is use an already-defined list to make this whole process less manual when one day, I add a new column called "LIZARD". A list that I can just update with any changes:

```
animals <- c("cat","dog","bird")
```

Is there a way in R to use that list to basically run a loop that does *"for each item in animals, run `pet$item<- ifelse(pets$item== "item", 1, 0)`"*?

Very much appreciate the help. Wasn't able to find any similar questions.

Comment: `pets[, animals] <- +(pets[, animals] != 0)` are the columns only 0s and the column name or are there other labels besides "0" and "CAT" in the "CAT" column, for instance?

Comment: @rawr Maybe the comparison should be `!= "0"`?

Comment: @lmo `all(factor(0) == 0, factor('0') == 0, '0' == 0)`

Comment: @rawr Thanks for the clarification. Factors are a strange beast.

Comment: @rawr Oh, that's great! Works perfectly when I put the 0 in "". To clarify, I only had instances of 0s and the column name in each column. Thank you so much! I learned a few new techniques from your simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr` you could gather the data, adjust the column then spread it back. This uses the idea that your first 2 columns aren't animals as opposed to the vector of animals.

```
df %>% 
   gather(animal, value, -PERSON, -WEEK) %>% 
   mutate(value = ifelse(value == animal, 1, 0)) %>% 
   spread(animal, value)
```